# How to convert AccountId to Vec<u8> or vice versa

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I have a function which takes in [T::AccountId](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v3.0.0/frame_system/pallet/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.AccountId) type

```rust
    Citizen get(fn candidate_name): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) T::AccountId => Option<Vec<u8>>;
```

e.g.

```rust
    fn add_count(origin, account:T::AccountId, phrase: Vec<u8>) {
       // I need to concatenate : account + _ + phrase, then convert it to Vec<u8> or bytes
       // Then change the Citizen storage using account
    }
```

Another way is:

```rust
    fn add_count(origin, account:Vec<u8>, phrase: Vec<u8>) {
       // Concatenate : account + _ + phrase, then convert it to Vec<u8> or bytes
       // Then change account to T::AccountId and then change the Citizen storage
    }
```

But I am unable to convert the T::AccountId type to bytes/vec<u8> or vice versa.

Comment: have you tried `account.into()` ?

Comment: No, into() is not working

Comment: let vote_bytes: u8 = vote_account.into();  gives error => the trait `std::convert::From<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>` is not implemented for `u8

Comment: with account as `AccountID`?

Comment: Yes. account as AccountID

Comment: It's been this long this question been asked. Have you figured out an way @AmiyaBehera

Comment: @SudipGhimire No. Not sure if staurated_from can be used. https://crates.parity.io/sp_arithmetic/traits/trait.SaturatedConversion.html#method.saturated_into